# Nested lists addition

Tags: python-2.7, nested-lists

I have a nested list called `a`:

```
a = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

My desired output is a new list (`b`) containing the first list in `a`: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. Then I want to append to this list all of the values in `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]` added to the last number in `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`:

```
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Comment: What's your question? This just describes the problem. What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I haven't even written the code yet I need advice on where to start (complete beginner)

Comment: This isn't an appropriate place to ask then. You should already have gotten a start and be stuck in something specific that you can ask about. Broad "how do I do this" questions aren't ontopic. Get a start, and post back when you have a specific question that we can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Your First List
a =[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]

# Your Second List which is initalized as empty.
b = []

# Adding first list from (a) which is a[0] into second list 
# a[0] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# a[1] = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

b.extend(a[0])

# b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

# I then want to append to this list all of the values in [10, 11, 12, 13, 14] added 
# the last number in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

# a[0] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# a[0][-1] = 4 

last_val = a[0][-1]


second_list = a[1] # [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

for item in second_list:
  b.append(item+last_val)


print(b)  

# b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```